# Calculate what the new number should be

Tags: percentages

If I know that the price for a particular product is $1750 WITH a 35% discount

How can I found out what was the original price? This is probably a simple answer but I i have tried getting 35% and adding it to 1750, then 35% off that is a smaller number than 1750.

This isn't for study, purely just exporting a list of products, and I don't know there price before the sale price, and my client wants to know what the original prices were!

Comment: You've provided your own attempt, which is great.  It might also help if you could tell us what you're studying, so that the answer can be tailored to suit your level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1750=n-0.35n$ then $1750=0.65n$ then $n= 1750/0.65$ where n is the original price.

Note: the answer might depend on how the "discount" is calculated.

Comment: Okay, I'm no math genius at all, but I have no idea how to actually calculate that

Comment: How can I put "n" in the equation if I don't know its value? I'm confused

Comment: @ShannonHochkins  Note that $n$ is the value before the discount is applied.  As Bor Kari demonstrated, $n = \frac{1750}{0.65}$.

Comment: you just have to divide $1750$ by $0.65$. This is because the original amount was multiplied by $0.65$ as we had a $35$% discount. So we divide by $1750$ by $0.65$

Comment: I'm confused as to where 0.65 came from? How did we arrive at this number?

Comment: The discount was $35$ % so we are paying for $65$ % of the item only. so we can multiply the "original" value by 0.65 to get to the discounted price.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks that makes much more sense to me now!

Comment: $0.65n=n-0.35n$ models the equation.